# Disabling submit button onSubmit in Angular 9 web app so multiple form submissions do not occur

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, submit

I have an issue with my Angular 9 application sending multiple form submissions when a user clicks the submit button multiple times, I would like to disable the submit button once it has validated and submission is triggered up until the form has submitted and reset, I have designed the form to use modals for when a form is accepted or denied but quite often a user will click multiple times during loading, I have added a disabledSubmitButton boolean but this completely disables the submit button - ruining the user experience by also disabling the incorrect form fields modal. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my contact form HTML

```
<div class="container section-title-hero text-center msf">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">

    <mdb-card class="mt-3 mb-3">

      <mdb-card-body class="px-lg-5 pt-0">
        <div class="row">
          <div class=" msf msfc col mt-3">
            <h5>Send us a message</h5>
          </div>
        </div>

        <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div style="color: #030A8c !important; padding-bottom: 1em;" class="md-form mt-3">
            <input type="text" formControlName="contactFormName" id="materialContactFormName" class="form-control"
              mdbInput mdbValidate />
            <label for="materialContactFormName">Name</label>
            <mdb-error *ngIf="contactFormName.invalid && (contactFormName.dirty || contactFormName.touched)"><i
                class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Please
              enter your name</mdb-error>
            <mdb-success *ngIf="contactFormName.valid && (contactFormName.dirty || contactFormName.touched)"><i
                class=" fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </mdb-success>
          </div>

          <div style="color: #030A8c !important; padding-bottom: 1em;" class="md-form">
            <input type="email" formControlName="contactFormEmail" id="materialContactFormEmail" class="form-control"
              mdbInput mdbValidate />
            <label for="materialContactFormEmail">E-mail</label>
            <mdb-error *ngIf="contactFormEmail.invalid && (contactFormEmail.dirty || contactFormEmail.touched)"><i
                class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Please
              enter your email</mdb-error>
            <mdb-success *ngIf="contactFormEmail.valid && (contactFormEmail.dirty || contactFormEmail.touched)"><i
                class=" fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </mdb-success>
          </div>




          <div style="color: #030A8c !important; padding-bottom: 1em;" class="md-form">
            <input type="text" formControlName="contactFormSubjects" id="materialContactFormSubjects"
              class="form-control" mdbInput mdbValidate />
            <label for="materialContactFormSubjects">Subject</label>
            <mdb-error
              *ngIf="contactFormSubjects.invalid && (contactFormSubjects.dirty || contactFormSubjects.touched)">
              <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Please enter a subject</mdb-error>
            <mdb-success
              *ngIf="contactFormSubjects.valid && (contactFormSubjects.dirty || contactFormSubjects.touched)">
              <i class=" fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></mdb-success>
          </div>


          <div style="color: #030A8c !important; padding-bottom: 1em;" class="md-form">
            <textarea type="text" formControlName="contactFormMessage" id="materialContactFormMessage"
              class="form-control md-textarea" mdbInput mdbValidate></textarea>
            <label for="materialContactFormMessage">Message</label>
            <mdb-error *ngIf="contactFormMessage.invalid && (contactFormMessage.dirty || contactFormMessage.touched)">
              <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Please enter a message</mdb-error>
            <mdb-success *ngIf="contactFormMessage.valid && (contactFormMessage.dirty || contactFormMessage.touched)">
              <i class=" fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></mdb-success>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="md-form">
                <mdb-checkbox mdbValidate formControlName="contactFormCopy">Send me a copy of this message
                </mdb-checkbox>
                <mdb-error *ngIf="copy.invalid && (copy.dirty || copy.touched)">Input invalid</mdb-error>
                <mdb-success *ngIf="copy.valid && (copy.dirty || copy.touched)">Input valid</mdb-success>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <button mdbBtn (click)="openModal()" color="info" outline="true" rounded="true"
                class="z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect" mdbWavesEffect type="submit" [disabled]="disabledSubmitButton">
                Send
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>


      </mdb-card-body>

    </mdb-card>
  </div>
</div>
<!--  End Contact Section -->

<app-branch-locations></app-branch-locations>
<!-- Start Branch Locations Section -->



<div class="container">
  <hr>
</div>
```

And here is the contact form typescript

```
import { ConnectionService } from '../../connection.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

// Modals
import { ContactmailmodalComponent } from '../../views/modals/contact/contactmailmodal/contactmailmodal.component';
import { ContactvalidationmodalComponent } from '../../views/modals/contact/contactvalidationmodal/contactvalidationmodal.component';

import { MDBModalRef, MDBModalService } from 'ng-uikit-pro-standard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {





  disabledSubmitButton: boolean = true;
  // Contact Form
  contactForm: FormGroup;
// disabledSubmitButton: boolean = true;
optionsSelect: Array<any>;


modalRef: MDBModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: MDBModalService, fb: FormBuilder, private connectionService: ConnectionService) {

  this.contactForm = fb.group({
    'contactFormName': ['', Validators.required],
    'contactFormEmail': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
    'contactFormSubjects': ['', Validators.required],
    'contactFormMessage': ['', Validators.required],
    // 'contactFormCopy': ['', Validators.requiredTrue],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.optionsSelect = [
    { value: 'Feedback', label: 'Feedback' },
    { value: 'Report a bug', label: 'Report a bug' },
    { value: 'Feature request', label: 'Feature request' },
    { value: 'Other stuff', label: 'Other stuff' },
    ];
  }

  get contactFormName() {
    return this.contactForm.get('contactFormName');
  }
  get contactFormEmail() {
    return this.contactForm.get('contactFormEmail');
  }
  get contactFormSubjects() {
    return this.contactForm.get('contactFormSubjects');
  }
  get contactFormMessage() {
    return this.contactForm.get('contactFormMessage');
  }
  // get copy() {
  //   return this.contactForm.get('contactFormCopy');
  // }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.contactForm.valid) {
      console.log("form submitted");


      this.connectionService.sendMessage(this.contactForm.value).subscribe(

        () => {
          this.disabledSubmitButton = true;
          this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ContactmailmodalComponent);


        },

        (error) => {
          console.log("Error", error);
        }

      );
    } else {
      // validate all form fields
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
        ContactvalidationmodalComponent
      );
      Object.keys(this.contactForm.controls).forEach((field) => {
        // {1}
        const control = this.contactForm.get(field); // {2}
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true }); // {3}
      });
    }
  }
  openModal() {

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe disabling and enabling the button according to which step you are at. You want it disabled to prevent multiple submissions, so disable it just until the request is sent and the modal appears and then re-enable it.
Here's how I would go about addressing this..

```
onSubmit() {
if (this.contactForm.valid) {
  console.log("form submitted");
  this.disabledSubmitButton = true; // disable the button once the onSubmit is triggered

  this.connectionService.sendMessage(this.contactForm.value).subscribe(

    () => {

      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ContactmailmodalComponent);
      this.disabledSubmitButton = false; // re-enable the button once the modal shows

    },

    (error) => {
      console.log("Error", error);
      this.disabledSubmitButton = false; // Should re-enable the button if an error occurs aswell 
    }

  );
} else {
  // validate all form fields
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
    ContactvalidationmodalComponent
  );
  Object.keys(this.contactForm.controls).forEach((field) => {
    // {1}
    const control = this.contactForm.get(field); // {2}
    control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true }); // {3}
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmed, this worked! I also had to change disabledSubmitButton: boolean = true; to disabledSubmitButton: boolean; for anyone with this issue in the future I am forever in your debt.

Comment: Glad I could be of help :) @HarryCardno